# woocommerce subscription free trail text

Tags: paypal, woocommerce, wordpress, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to setup woocommerce subscriptions so that all paypal standard payments fall on the same day by using the free trial feature.

But the problem I'm having is changing the text when this feature is used so the customer doesn't get confused.

At the moment on the product page is says "£24.95 / month with a 2-day free trial" when ideally it needs to say "£24.95 / month starting in 2 days" or similar

In the cart is says "A 2-day free trial then £24.95 / month" when I would like it to say "A £24.95 / month starting in 2 days" or similar

And lastly when the customer gets taken to PayPal's secure servers is says under terms "Free for the first 2 days. Then £24.95 GBP for each month" when I would like this changed to "£24.95 GBP for each month starting in 2 days time" or similar

Would anyone know if there are any filter hooks I can use to get the desired effect, or if there is anything else I can do?

The site only has one product so I hope it's going to be straight forward.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt whether you can change PayPal's messages, but Woocommerce's, probably (does it come with .mo/.po files?). Either way, none of my business, but - your choice of wording would confuse me as a customer, and I'm sure the trial feature is not supposed to be used to time charges

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/want-to-replace-cart-text-everywhere-on-wocomerce-with-basket

Comment: Using the free trial feature is a work around when using paypal standard as you can not change the payment date. See option 1 on their manual - http://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/faq/#align-payment-dates

As for the choice of wording, this is purely as an example and is given as a reference only

Comment: Ah, OK. Fair enough. Check out the links in the link above, this is likely to be in Woocommerce's translation files and you should be able to change it there.

Comment: Thank you.
Just hope that the text being shown on paypal's paypament page is being passed in it's entirety by woocommerce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string'` filter can be used to customise the price displayed for a product.

The `'woocommerce_subscription_price_string'` filter can be used to customise the cart/order prices displayed in the cart and on an order.

For examples of how to build your price strings and details of the parameters passed to each filter, view the source of the `WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_price_string()` and `WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_subscription_price_string()` functions. I always try to write self-documenting code & include PHPDoc for anything that is not self evident.

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: It does and I'm honoured to have a reply from the Woo Subscription godfather himself. Thank you.

Comment: BTW, would you know how much customisation can be done for the terms on the paypal payment page? - http://imgur.com/SzuH1dL

Comment: @user2232826 unfortunately, it's not possible to customise the language/string used by PayPal at all when using PayPal Standard. It is possible with PayPal Express Checkout/Digital Goods. The WooCommerce Digital Goods extension will display the same string displayed on your site to the customer at PayPal.

Comment: Brent, what's the parameters for woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string?

I see them for woocommerce_subscription_price_string but not for woocommerce_subscriptions_product_price_string. Reference - http://docs.woothemes.com/document/subscriptions/develop/filter-reference/